# he argument type 'Future<void> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<void> Function(App)?'

Tags: flutter

[code for main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G66Av.png)

I recieve this error after flutter run

/C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_web-5.2.4/lib/firebase_auth_web.dart:92:45: Error: The argument
type 'Future Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future Function(App)?'.

- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'App' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/src/interop/app.dart'
  ('/C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_web-2.2.2/lib/src/interop/app.dart').
  FirebaseCoreWeb.registerService('auth', () async {

Tried flutter clean and downloaded flutter core web

Comment: add the code which is causing the issue

Comment: You can for more about [asking good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I wrote several codes therefore finding it hard to track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading the project dependencies worked for me. Use the commands below

```bash
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
```

Comment: I also added firebase_auth_web